# Add color to cell by formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

How to add any text formatting to highlight a cell which have hyperlink by formula.

```
=HYPERLINK("xxx", "Textual Information")
```

This is how I am creating hyperlinks.

After surfing through google I was able to find conditional formatting but not the one i want.

Note: This is a part of pdf to excel conversion and everything is dynamic and I can't make formatting cell specific, that is why I am looking for solution in form of formula.

Comment: Formulas cannot access the cell's color as far as I know. You either need to use Conditional Formatting or VBA.

Comment: Any other way to highlight or differentiate cells which have hyperlinks in it?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'd recommend Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/change-the-font-format-for-hyperlinks-672c2905-ad3e-40be-b281-811e68386243)? You can change the fill as well.

Comment: @BigBen, No, but it gave me an answer that it can't be done in any form. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a cell with hyperlink and how you would like to format that cell? I think `Conditional Formatting` may be able to do the job depends on what you want to achieved and where exactly you want to apply the format.